# MySQL or PHP keeps returning a null

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am trying to execute a query through parameters using mysqli. It works normally for other procedures, but for this specific procedure, it keeps returning a null.

I cross-referenced every single detail I could find, but for some strange reason, it does not like what it receives.

I tested the query using Workbench and it seems to work without an issue, but it does not execute via php for this brain scratcher.

The Stored Procedure that does the insert and it receives 10 parameters.

```
 PROCEDURE `usp_Advert`(IN `advertID` VARCHAR(50),
 IN `sellerID` VARCHAR(100),
 IN `make` VARCHAR(30),
 IN `model` VARCHAR(30),
 IN `description` varchar(100),
 IN `mileage` int(11),
 IN `color` VARCHAR(100),
 IN `price` int(8),
 IN `cityID` int(11),
 IN `year` int(4))
BEGIN
Declare errorNo int;
Declare Exit Handler for sqlexception
Begin
Get current diagnostics condition 1 errorNo = Mysql_errno;
select errorNo as MYSQL_ERROR;
Rollback;
end;

start transaction;
set autocommit=0;
set @now := curdate();
if((select count(a.advertID) from `vas`.advert as a where a.advertID=`advertID`)>=1)then
select true as `tryagain`;
else
insert into vas.advert
(`advertID`,
`sellerID`,
`vehicleMake`,
`vehicleModel`,
`advertDescription`,
`vehicleMileage`,
`vehicleColor`,
`sellingPrice`,
`cityID`,
`advertDate`,
`advertExpireDate`,
`vehicleYear`)
VALUES
(`advertID`,
`sellerID`,
`make`,
`model`,
`description`,
`mileage`,
`color`,
`price`,
`cityID`,
@now,
null,
`year`);
END IF;
IF (row_count()>0) then
select true;
end if;
COMMIT WORK;
end
```

The Database connection

```
namespace DAL;
class DB
{
    // Local setup
    private static $dbHost = '127.0.0.1';
    private static $dbUser = 'username';
    private static $dbPass = 'password';
    private static $dbName = 'db';

    protected static function Connect()
    {
        return mysqli_connect(self::$dbHost, self::$dbUser, self::$dbPass, self::$dbName);
    }
}
```

The Helper that does a selection with parameters.

```
<?php
        namespace DAL;

        require_once '../DAL/DBHelper.php';

        class DBHandler
        {
        public static function SelectParam($query, array $param)
            {
                //Variables
                $arrayType = null;
                //Format Calculation Loop
                foreach ($param as $element) {
                    if (is_string($element)) {
                        $arrayType .= 's';
                    } else if (is_int($element)) {
                        $arrayType .= 'i';
                    } else if (is_double($element)) {
                        $arrayType .= 'd';
                    }
                    else if(is_bool($element))
                    {
                        $arrayType .='b';
                    }
                }
                //Open Connection
                $conn = DB::Connect();
                //Prepare Query

//Somewhere here it breaks, but I cannot find the answer.
                $call = mysqli_prepare($conn, $query);
                //Bind Query
                call_user_func_array(array($call, 'bind_param'), array_merge(array($arrayType),$param));
                //Execute Query
                mysqli_stmt_execute($call);
                //Fetch Result
                $result = mysqli_stmt_get_result($call);
                //Fill Row
                $row = mysqli_fetch_all($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
                //Close Connection
                mysqli_close($conn);
                //Return Result
                return $row;
            }
    }
```

The Handler that parses the query and parameters to the Helper.

```
<?php
namespace DAL;

require_once '../DAL/DBHelper.php';

class DBHandler
{
    public static function Advertise($advertID,$sellerID,$vehicleMake,$vehicleModel,$description,$price,$mileage,$color,$cityID, $vehicleYear)
    {
        $sp='CALL usp_Advert(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)';
        $param = array(&$advertID,&$sellerID,&$vehicleMake,&$vehicleModel,&$description,&$price,&$mileage,&$color,&$cityID,&$vehicleYear);
        return DBHelper::SelectParam($sp,$param);
    }
}
```

The Business logic layer that actually sends the values through...

```
<?php
require_once '../BLL/CORS_Headers.php';

require_once '../DAL/DBHandler.php';

use DAL\DBHandler;
 //$json=json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));
$json_encode(DBHandler::Advertise('dsknfdsnnfd','email@address.com','Toyota','Regius','it is cool',10000,10000,'Blue',1,2006));
?>
```

The values does make their way to the DBHelper, but it keeps returning a null when it is trying to bind the values to the parameters.

I tried altering tiny bits of code, but the result is still the same. All the other calls work, but this one decides not to.

Comment: Uhm are you really opening a new connection foreach running SELECT ?  You should be really refactor to use singleton pattern instead to reuse the connection..

Comment: technically speaking this is for a RestAPI

Comment: then it makes sense more or less, maybe also take a look into [GraphQL](https://graphql.org/) as REST is more or less superseded by GraphQL (meant as research option)

Comment: *"The values does make their way to the DBHelper, but it keeps returning a null when it is trying to bind the values to the parameters."*  i supecting the problem to a in `$param = array(&$advertID,&$sellerID,&$vehicleMake,&$vehicleModel,&$description,&$price,&$mileage,&$color,&$cityID,&$vehicleYear);` try without passing as references..  Or `call_user_func_array(array($call, 'bind_param'), array_merge(array($arrayType),$param));`  which might be needed to be refractored as a loop more or less -> `foreach($param ...) { $call->bind_param(..) };`

Comment: But i would suggest using [FirePHP](http://www.firephp.org/) to debug on logical positions in the code.. To see what the code does, what the values are and if the values are what you woud expect..  As FirePHP is alot more easy and readable then using `echo '<pre>'; var_dump($var); echo '</pre>'; exit()` kind of debugging

Comment: debugging further, I notices by echoing the bind at call_user_func_array(array($call, 'bind_param'), array_merge(array($arrayType),$param)); returns a true, but the execute (next line) returns a false.

Comment: Anyhow -> `ini_set('display_errors',1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);` and run again..   That should enable exceptions on mysqli lib so you know directly why the execute is false..

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out

My referencing was just just swapped in my BLL

Instead of...

```
json_encode(DBHandler::Advertise('dsknfdsnnfd','email@address.com','Toyota','Regius','it is cool',10000,10000,'Blue',1,2006));
```

It should have been...

```
json_encode(DBHandler::Advertise('dsknfdsnnfd','email@address.com','Toyota','Regius','WORK',10000,'Blue',10000,1,1998));
```